# What is it called when you use <img> tags and display an image from another website?

Tags: html

I heard a term for this a few years ago and can't remember what the term for it is, but basically what is the term for when you use  tags to display an image on your site, but the image it's displaying is from site B and rather than uploading it to your own site, you're just using where it's stored on site B.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_linking

Comment: CDN, hot linking, web scrapping?

Comment: @cutiko hot linking is the term they used, but yes, inline linking is the same thing. Thanks and thanks for not giving me a hard time, I had just been looking for this term for a long time now with no success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the term you are looking for is "embedding"

Or, more specifically for images, there is "inline linking"...